# DB2 - migrate schema from v9.5 to v10.1

Tags: db2

I have a schema in a DB2 v9.5 database, which has 20 tables under it. Now I need to migrate all the tables under this schema to a new DB2 v10.1 database. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of Now I am using db2move export/import to move data between two sets of tables (v9.5 and v10.1)

Thanks,
Naidu

Comment: I was looking for if there's any better solution, but I used db2move eventually.

Answer (score 0):

IBM has an [Upgrade Guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.upgrade.doc/doc/c0023662.html) on Info Center that goes through all the steps needed to upgrade from a lower version to DB2 v10.1 (I'm guessing you're on Linux/Unix/Windows here, since you say from 9.5 to 10.1).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i'm not looking to upgrade, i need both db2 database to be on different version, i just need to copy a schema from 9.5 to 10.1